# How do i remove or disable jquery.min.map and jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.map so I do not get a 404 error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, source-maps, jquery-source-map

I am running jquery-1.9.1.min.js and jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js on my website, which I believe is automatically loading jquery.min.map and jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.map, but returning 404 error because the browser cannot find it.

How can I remove or disable loading jquery.min.map and jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.map?
Is the best way to prevent getting 404 errors is to create empty .map files?

Thanks!
~ Joshua ~

Comment: Can you at least show us the markup where you're including the jQuery files?

Comment: @JayBlanchard - [nejmgroup.org](http://nejmgroup.org/)

Comment: It would better if you added the code here so that it can be preserved for future reference.